# Where can i find some practical tutorial or exercise about ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frontend

I'm new to ember.js, where can i find some practical tutorial or exercise about it? I try with some online tutorials and vids but i can't find anything that can help me to start with this library.

Comment: You should read the guides from the ember site, is better for you because you can learn the basis of the library, if you look for a step by step tutorial maybe you can create something but you will never understand whats going on behind the scenes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [emberwatch.com](http://emberwatch.com), it contains plenty of information,

- Talks
- Tutorials
- Screencasts
- Example apps
- Podcasts
- etc. etc.

Anything else I could mention is already listed there.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quickly read on the site's library and I have found a guide that apparently has some videos and is good explained.
Have you tried?

http://emberjs.com/guides

Comment: Thank you! Yes, i try, but except the introductive video i didn't found any exercise or practice