# Returning an array from the model

Tags: ember.js

I am very new to ember and what I am trying to do is get the data from the model into an array.

Currently I am doing:

```
var playerList = App.Player.find().toArray();
```

But it's not returning me an array of players it's returning an array of the objects? ex:

```
<App.Player:ember311:1>,<App.Player:ember332:2>,<App.Player:ember338:3>,<App.Player:ember344:4>,<App.Player:ember350:5>,<App.Player:ember356:6>,<App.Player:ember362:7>,<App.Player:ember368:8>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App.Player.find()` returns a promise, and therefore you should wait until your records are fully loaded before doing operations on them. From your question it's not entirely clear how you player objects do look like. But to get to your players, and especially to your player's properties, you could do something like:

```
var playerList = App.Player.find().then(function (result) {
  // This callback will fire when array is loaded
  // and this is the correct way to get to the records
  result.objectAt(0).get('name'); // assuming "name" is a property of your model

  // here you can then loop over your obejcts
  result.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.get('name'));
  });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: While I am still new at this, do you have any recommended sources for learning Ember? Thanks again!

Comment: of course, take a look at this answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490541/where-can-i-find-some-practical-tutorial-or-exercise-about-ember-js/17490813#17490813 or take the shortcut: http://emberwatch.com :)